# AudioSessionInitialize returning inscrutable error code

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, audio

I'm calling `AudioSessionInitialize` like so

```
OSStatus result = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL,NULL,interruptionListener,NULL);
```

and getting the result `0xbfffde94` (i.e. `-1073750040`) which doesn't match anything in the documentation, which are all readable 4CC's like `'!ini'` and so forth.

The good news is that it *seems* like the call worked. Nevertheless, can anyone shed light on this error code?

EDIT: The above error code is returned in the simulator. On the device the error code is `2fffe810`.

Comment: Bizarre. Is this on the device or the simulator? Or both?

Comment: Incidentally, from the way all this is behaving, I kinda feel like these numbers returned are memory addresses. I inspected the memory and it kinda looked like storage for various variables might. (E.g. similarity in 4-byte groups.) It was 4 bytes of 0 at the address returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm an idiot. There was an error in the macro I had wrapping the call & reporting the error, which called the AudioSessionInitialize twice. That doesn't quite explain the error code I saw, but it sure isn't worth wondering about.

UPDATE: Actually this is pretty slapstick so I'm going to explain.

The offending macro was originally:

```
#define CHECK(S) { OSStatus err = (S); if (S) printf("Error %x at \"%s\"\n", err, #S);}
```

so bug #1 is the `if (S)` which should be if `if (err)`. Hence I'm repeating every call to the audio system, which explains various other weird things, so I'm very happy I tried to figure out what had seemed like a harmless anomaly. In this case the second call complained that the audio session was already initialized.

But why the weird error code? I wanted to see the 4CC's so I changed the macro to this, carrying the error along:

```
#define CHECK(S) { OSStatus err[2] = {S,0}; if (S) printf("Error %x '%4s' at \"%s\"\n", err, &err, #S); }
```

(The second OSStatus of 0 terminates the string defined by the 4CC first OSStatus, so I can print it with format `%s`.) But I forgot to change `err` to `err[0]`, so it was indeed printing the address of the `err` array. This I'm pretty sure is correct now:

```
#define CHECK(S) { OSStatus err[2] = {S,0}; if (*err) printf("Error %x '%4s' at \"%s\"\n", *err, err, #S); }
```

Comment: hehe - great :) ... With the words of Forest Gump: shit happens, I guess. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Since these results are bogus and not defined or described by Apple, I am left with only but one assumption; you have a weird mix of Frameworks installed - possibly old versions mixed with newer ones. So all I could recommend is to reinstall the entire iPhone SDK.

Comment: I built and ran on a different machine, and got sort of the same thing, `0xbfffdf54` in the simulator. Then in my project I replaced the AudioToolbox.framework in /System/Library/Frameworks with the one in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (sure that this would solve it) but got the same problem, different error code `0xbfffe0a4`. Still, maybe you're right, somehow.

Comment: Did you try any of Apple's examples using sound output? If not, go ahead test something like e.g.MusicCube. Do they receive proper values  from the AudioSessionInitialize?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the OSStatus variable in the debugger's list of variables (lower left). Right click on it and select View Value As->Bytes (Hex with ASCII). Read the 4-letter code backwards.* This should match one of the documented result codes.

A value of 1768843636 is 74 69 6e 69 when viewed this way. Next to that the debug window shows 'tini'. Turn that around and you get 'init', which the documentation says is kAudioSessionAlreadyInitialized.

*No, I don't know why.

Comment: I get that, but the status codes I was seeing (see above) were not readable as 4-character-codes.

Comment: \* Also, I know why. The processor is little-endian\*\*, so e.g. 0x74696e69 is store in memory as 69,6e,69,74. And 4cc's are like base-256 numbers so the character constant 'init' appears in memory as 't','i','n','i'. [\*\*The ARM processor is "bi-endian" but little-endian by default and in this case.]